# Xcode Json returns nil in array

Tags: objective-c, json

I don't see what i am doing wrong here but i can't get the JSON back good in the array..

this is what JSON returns:

(html)

```
"Response": {
    "objecten": {
        "object": [
            {
                "id": "12345
```

(Xcode)

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"object"];
if (array == nil) {
    NSLog(@"No 'data' in array");
    return;
}
```

i get the error because its nil, but if i fill in @"Response" instead of @"object" i get an array back with data.

Then i loop thrue it

```
for (NSDictionary *resultDict in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@",resultDict);
```

and it has only "objecten" nothing more...

So what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: that's not valid JSON, it needs to be completed.

Comment: We're assuming your are converting JSON to your collection types somewhere, e.g. `NSJSONSerialization` but you should show it...

Comment: left the other stuff out (its a complete JSON i checked it with JSONLint)

@NSBum i am using AFnetworking and after the code i wrote i am checking for the collection but the dictionary is empty.. thats the problem (i checked it with the NSlog)

Maybe because of the hierarchy or something ? Response/objecten/object thats not possible right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a tree of objects. Try:

```
NSArray * arr =[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"objecten"] objectForKey:@"object"]]];
```

Comment: Thanks! i knew it had to do something with the hierarchy/tree but i didn't know how to fix it!!